# which are the most informative .net screencasts watched by you?

Tags: .net

I have learned so much from http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/ nhibernate screen casts that i wonder why they are given as free!. Did you know about other such .net screen casts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob Conery's [MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/) series has been excellent. It has covered a lot of ground, not limited to ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I learned a lot with the [ASP .NET Videos](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/)

There are some other good videos [here](http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/Browse.aspx) also.

Answer (score 1):

How about [DNR TV](http://www.dnrtv.com/)